# How can I copy iPhone photo album to new machine?

Tags: itunes, iphone, photos

I lost my laptop and all need to sync all my photos (both in camera and photo album) in the iPhone to my new machine (with iTunes 9)

Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to clarify whether you're on a pc or a mac.
If you're on a mac, theres a really good application called phoneview (sorry, can't post links yet)

It's not too expensive and it can copy any content of your iPhone.
But just so you know, the pictures from your photo albums are a reduced size. They are not the full resolution.

Good luck
//Ulrik

Answer (score 1):

Why not use iTunes to sync all photos to the new system ? otherwise, the moment I connect my iPhone to my computer ( both Windows + Linux) the folder containing all photos is available, just copy them to your laptop.

You can also use [iPhone Explorer](http://www.iphone-explorer.com/)

Comment: This will not allow me to copy photo albums

Comment: just photos. not photo albums